# Syntax error in Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
{select 
IIF(PA.ES='Acceptable',1,
IIF(PA.ES='Warning',2,
IIF(PA.ES='Critical',3, 
IIF(PA.ES='No Need to Report','NNTR','NR')))) AS Overall_Health
from
qry_tEMP AS PA}
```

My id has `ES = No Need to Report`, but when I run it in this fashion I get

```
Overall_Health
#Error
```

My goal is to display the value as is.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that sometimes the `IIF` expressions return a number (`1`, `2` or `3`) and sometimes a string (`NNTR`, `NR`).  Try quoting the numbers.  If that doesn't work, you'll need an Access specialist (meaning "someone other than me").

Comment: Indeed, you can't mix data types. Query columns must return same type. Remember Access isn't Excel! There are database rules.